# Blank screen displaying in Webview instead of webpage

Tags: android, webview

I am displaying a Graph in Android webview, previously it was working fine..but today i am getting blank screen instead of graph. what might be the reason. i am debugging the code but i didn't find any exception or any uncertain condition in debugging information.
Please help me out.

`wv.loadUrl(mUrl);`

Is the line which takes "mUrl" as input. and loads the webpage in Webview.

Comment: From where you get the graph. provide source code so that someone can help you.

Comment: I am calling Google Chart API to draw the graphs. I have updated my question.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: check the url in browser once

Comment: Thanks folks. The problem is solved.

Comment: @Abhi: That URL works fine in browser and now working in Android Webview-webpage too. Thanks.

Comment: I had made changes in .xml file related to webview. I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are making a request over network for fetching your data (Correct me if wrong). IF that is the case its always recommended to use an asynctask.

You can get the details here for the same:
http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructs-part-3.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The problem is solved Thanks.